# Hadoop Key-Value store with remote deploy

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hazelcast, ignite, apache-kudu

My application is launched from remotely pc via spark-submit in yarn-cluster mode with Kerberos keytab and principals by this guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html. The advantages of this approach are that I have my own version of the spark at any cluster.

Is it possible to automatically deploy Ignite/Hazelcast/Accumulo/Kudu or other NoSQL DB with random access on read/write into a Hadoop YARN cluster without sftp/ssh only by running a bash-script with HADOOP_CONF_DIR/YARN_CONF_DIR configs?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Hazelcast on a YARN cluster is possible and easy, take a look at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-yarn